# Flutter/Dart: Why does this statement effect null-nafety?

Tags: flutter, dart, null, dart-null-safety

I realized this is just fine:

```dart
List<int> list = [];
int? b;
void addBarIfNull() {
  if (b != null) {
    list.add(b);  // no problem
  }
}
```

But adding this one statement `b = null` after adding b to the list, lets the linter complain with: `The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'`:

```dart
List<int> list = [];
int? b;
void addBarIfNull() {
  if (b != null) {
    list.add(b);  // problem: The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'
    b = null;
  }
}
```

Can someone explain what is going on here? Why is `b` considered as `int?` in `list.add(b)` if we clearly check before that it is not null? Why do both code snippets differ in handling this?

Comment: Unless `addBarIfNull` is a nested function within another function, it is *not* fine.  Only *local* variables can be type-promoted.  See https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons.  It also hints about why your second case doesn't work; by writing back to `b`, you demote it back to a nullable type, and flow analysis apparently isn't smart enough to handle that better.

Comment: @jamesdlin is right the doc is very clear. As per the doc "you can work around all of these non-promotion examples by adding a redundant check—code that confirms a condition that’s already been checked. If the promotion that’s failing is a null check, use !"

or you can initialize the list of int with nullable int. List<int?> list = []; Like this.

Answer (score -1):

```
    It is null safey issue when you declare 
{
int? b; 

}
you allow b to be null or have value but when you try to add
{
 list.add(b);  
}
b to the list you don't allow the list to contain null value that why the error message said you can't add int? to int you need to allow the list to contain null value if that whta you needed.

{
List<int?> list =[];
}
```

Comment: before adding b to the list, it is explicitly checked that b != null, therefore b is clearly of type int (not int?) when the add happens. This confused me.

Comment: Yes b is int but the question is about null safety whether the list allow null or not.  Thus since you allow b to be null allow list to contain null but you can change what happen to b when null